# angular js use input value in controller on ng-change function is always empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a input text box value in controller on ng-change function and so I associate a model(searchSP) with it. When I console the model value its empty always. What I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
<input type="text"  ng-model = "searchSP"  ng-change ="getSPList()" class="form-control" name="select_names"  placeholder="Enter Name" value="">
```

JS

```
App.controller("spCtrl",function($scope){
 $scope.searchSP = '';

 $scope.getSPList= function(){
    console.log($scope.searchSP);
    $scope.sparams = {
        'pageLimit'     :   10,
        'entryLimit'     :  10,
        'orderBy'       :   '', 
        'order'         :   'ASC',
        'searchQuery'   :   $scope.searchSP,
    };
  }

 })
```

Comment: you need to expand your code, this looks like a working example

Comment: HI, this is my actual code I just changed my controller name here

Comment: This looks like working example, please add full code.

Comment: @UIDeveloper here is a working example: [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kw81T53WjusWKvVxvcMg?p=preview)

Comment: I applied the example.No problem.Does an error appear on devtools.Can you add your full code.maybe there's something escaping your eye

Comment: @UIDeveloper, which angularjs version you are using?

Comment: I am using Angular js  1